# Crop this with HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
.FirstBox {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 78px;
  height: 60px
}

#BgVideo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -150px;
  top: -650px;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div class="FirstBox">
  <h1 id="h1">Our secrets</h1>
  <div id="BgVideo">
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop width="1640px" height="2060px" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

i tried overflow: hidden; in firstbox class and bgvideo too but didnt work.
i wanna video just be in first box.
video height is 964px.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is there any way you can provide an absolute reference for your video so we can see exactly what we're working with?

Comment: Welcome, in addition to Kameron's question... Are you trying to make the video to be a background with other content over the top or is the video simply to be slapped onto your page with all your wording etc?

Comment: Yes i try to put video in my navbar and i could do that but i can't cut waste part of video.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.FirstBox {
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* make absolute positioning relative to this div */
  position: relative;
}

#BgVideo {
  /* calculating height based on the 100% of viewport width and the aspect ratio. */
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(9 / 16 * 100vw);
  /* center video using absolute positioning */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* place the video tag under everything inside .FirstBox div */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="FirstBox">
  <h1>Our secrets</h1>
  <video id="BgVideo" autoplay muted> <!-- use the video tag properly with a source tag -->
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanksss, it works!

Comment: I'm gald I could help :D

Comment: can you make it the accepted question?

Comment: @Gaurav you should consider marking an answer as accepted if it helped you/solved your issue.